# React.js Update data when editing finished, but poll progress while user is inputting data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using browser based BLE, which only allows one update to happen at a time.

I want to send updates to the device as soon as a user does something, but only sending the last update needed between update calls (So no queuing and sending one at a time).

I've created the below example to illustrate the problem.

If you click the button quickly x times. I would like it to update the device as soon as possible, but it can only send an update after the last update is completed.

I don't want to setup "sending" modal preventing actions while it's sending.

The below code works(ish), but still prone to clashing still, the reason for the UseEffect is to make sure the last state of the data is sent.

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactjs-playground-forked-rqqhz5?file=/src/index.js:0-1219

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

// Fake ble calls
window.sending = false;

window.testSend = (n) => {
  if (window.sending) {
    throw new Error("Busy");
  }
  window.sending = true;

  console.log("DataSent: " + n);

  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.sending = false;
      resolve();
    }, 1000)
  );
};

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [sendingData, setSendingData] = useState(false);

  // Hack
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      window.testSend(count).then(() => setSendingData(false));
    }, 2000);

    return () => clearTimeout(id);
  }, [sendingData]);

  function inc() {
    setCount(count + 1);
    sendDataSlowly(count + 1);
  }

  function sendDataSlowly(newData) {
    if (sendingData) {
      return;
    }

    setSendingData(true);

    window.testSend(newData).then(() => setSendingData(false));
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={inc}>Click Me {count}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Is there a standard Patten / way of doing this type of delayed updating?

I've tried setting a "LastMissed" state, set before the return at the top of sendDataSlowly, but having trouble stopping it sending the correct data and not a previous one, or getting stuck in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error this seems to be working:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

// Fake ble calls
window.sending = false;

window.testSend = (n) => {
  if (window.sending) {
    throw new Error("Busy");
  }
  window.sending = true;

  console.log("DataSent: " + n);

  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.sending = false;
      resolve();
    }, 1000)
  );
};

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [sendingData, setSendingData] = useState(false);
  const [lastSent, setLastSent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      if(lastSent!=count)
      {
          sendDataSlowly(count);
      } 

  }, [sendingData,count]);

  function inc() {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }

  function sendDataSlowly(newData) {
    if (sendingData) {
    
      return;
    }

    setSendingData(true);

    window.testSend(newData).then(() => 
    {
        setSendingData(false);
        setLastSent(newData);
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={inc}>Click Me {count}</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```